# Can I limit applications log size in tomcat7?

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat7

We are developing a *Java Platform as a Service* (yes, another one!) for the java developers in our organization. Now we are in the point of asking ourselves, hey, what are we going to do with the **logs**?

As container we are using **tomcat 7**, so for the catalina logs it is clear: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html and follow the wise guidelines that **Mark Thomas** point out in this [presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Tuning-Tomcat-Mark-Thomas) (around minute 10...)

But how can I limit the size of the *web applications logs*? Perhaps using the [security manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html)?

Thanks in advance,

Luis

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways I can think of you can do that outside of java and inside of java.

The outside of java way would be to use something like `logrotate`. This assumes that you are running on a *nix platform. `logrotate` allows you to specify which files are logs, how to long to keep them, when to roll them over to a new file, etc. It is highly configurable and probably already there.

The inside of java method would be to use `log4j`. The [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html) URL that you already specified had the first steps to setting up log4j. As you can see from the [configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) page it is extremely advanced. You can set up different loggers for different purposes and each one can have different files it would write to. `log4j` also has similar features as `logrotate` for the files it writes to.

Ultimately my recommendation would be to use `log4j`.

Comment: Thanks cogsmos! Yes, I agree with you in the use of the good and classic log4j. But my problem is to find out how to control the logs of the web applications that are deployed by the users?

Comment: Do you have any control over how they are using the Logger.getLogger() ?

Comment: mmm, no, not really, but maybe I could override the users log4j.properties like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258849/override-log4j-properties